# ENOSYS: function not implemented

Tags: npm, raspberry-pi, next.js, yarnpkg, raspberry-pi4

I recently install next js use to npm in raspi 4 with the raspbian operating system. Every time when I install react js, next js, and gatsby show me the same error.

---

At this time I install nextjs use yarn. also, I use npm and npx to show the same error. so I started to find a solution then somebody told me to use sudo so I  use sudo but doesn't work

```
sudo yarn create next-app
```

check my code error output

```
pi@raspberrypi:/media/pi/8243-BE00/next $ sudo yarn create next-app
yarn create v1.22.10
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
[4/4] Building fresh packages...

success Installed "create-next-app@10.0.5" with binaries:
      - create-next-app
✔ What is your project named? … myapp
Creating a new Next.js app in /media/pi/8243-BE00/next/myapp.

Installing react, react-dom, and next using yarn...

yarn add v1.22.10
info No lockfile found.
[1/4] Resolving packages...
warning next > chokidar > fsevents@2.1.3: "Please update to latest v2.3 or v2.2"
warning next > webpack > watchpack > watchpack-chokidar2 > chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
warning next > webpack > watchpack > watchpack-chokidar2 > chokidar > fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
warning next > resolve-url-loader > rework > css > urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
warning next > resolve-url-loader > rework > css > source-map-resolve > urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
warning next > resolve-url-loader > rework > css > source-map-resolve > resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
[2/4] Fetching packages...
info fsevents@2.1.3: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@2.1.3" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info fsevents@2.3.1: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@2.3.1" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info fsevents@1.2.13: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@1.2.13" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
error An unexpected error occurred: "ENOSYS: function not implemented, symlink '../../../../terser/bin/terser' -> '/media/pi/8243-BE00/next/myapp/node_modules/@ampproject/toolbox-optimizer/node_modules/.bin/terser'".
info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "/media/pi/8243-BE00/next/myapp/yarn-error.log".
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.

Aborting installation.
  yarnpkg add --exact react react-dom next --cwd /media/pi/8243-BE00/next/myapp has failed.

Done in 293.09s.
pi@raspberrypi:/media/pi/8243-BE00/next $
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this next:

1. Remove yarn.lock.
2. Remove node_modules.
3. Use the --ignore-optional FLAG (yarn --ignore-optional); these don’t install optional dependencies.

The fsevents package is for macOS only; you don't need it in Linux.

If any of that works you can remove ignore and see if .yarnclean works.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the log, looks like script is not able to create symbolic link

```
"ENOSYS: function not implemented, symlink '../../../../terser/bin/terser' -> '/media/pi/8243-BE00/next/myapp/node_modules/@ampproject/toolbox-optimizer/node_modules/.bin/terser'".
```

What is the file system you are using? I know exFAT and FAT32 don't support symbolic link.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/filesystem-functionality-comparison